# Country based cloudflare caching

Tags: caching, cdn, cloudflare, geoip

I have a website that shows different content depending on the user country, but I faced an issue with Cloudflare enabled, which caches full page output and returns wrongly for other countries.

Tried to look into custom cache keys or some ways to cache pages by country but couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is [Custom Cache Keys](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/cache-keys/) (available on the Enterprise plan). It allows you to include user features (such as country and language) in the key used to cache an object.